# Dumped Wort into Easy Clean Sanitizer

Tags: wort, sanitizer

I had a recent mishap in one of my brews in which I poured my wort into the primary fermenter, which was holding 1.5 gallons or so of Easy Clean. At that point, I didn't feel like wasting it, so I went ahead with the fermentation.  From what I gather from the MSDS, the active ingredients are sodium percarbonate and sodium sulfate; the former produces hydrogen peroxide for the sanitizing effect, while the latter appears to be a laxative...

Anyway, have any of y'all done this before by accident? I've read how people have made my same mistake with StarSan, though its active ingredient is much different (phosphoric acid). Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "While the latter appears to be a laxative..."   Let us know how it turns out. How much wort to the 1.5 gallons of sanitizer ?

Comment: It was a 5 gallon brew total...

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's OK with Star-San is because once the concentration drops, it just acts as free phosphates for the yeast to use. I would guess that hydrogen peroxide might be good for yeast (they like oxygen), not sure about the rest of it. A gallon and a half is quite a bit, definitely let us know how it turns out!

Comment: Definitely will! The yeast appeared pretty happy with the conditions, and the brew smelled pretty good while I was transferring it to the secondary. I'll probably try it out before I bottle it and let you all know what happens. =)

Answer (score 1):

I read over the data sheet.

[Easy Clean datasheet](https://storefront.ldcarlson.com/storefrontCommerce/binaryContent.do?contentKey=ac7e3b4d-ddaa-4dfb-ac44-b5a59546039f)

Not something you want to take a swig of straight, in the that event it does state to call a doctor and drink lots of water. Which suggests dilution helps to make it "safer".

It's not a carcinogen so that's good.

But it does say not to contaminate food or beverages with it.

Sound like the yeast made a go of it. Let us know how it turn out.

I doubt this will happen in your case because it was mostlikly mixed pretty fast. But I've had about 1/2 gallon if starsan suck back in to beer before. What it did was float on top, like a black and tan would, so I was able to rack the beer out leaving most of the starsan behind.

I've had

Comment: When I try to go to that link I get `Application Error.
An unrecoverable error has occurred. Proceed to the Home page and try again. If the problem persists, contact your system administrator`